# ADFS url Case Sensitivity

Tags: c#, adfs2.0, adfs

Does anyone know how to make the url for your web application that uses adfs case insensitive? right now if i try to browse my app with case different than what i have provided in my web.config under returnurl it gives me system error.
any help?

```
  <websso>
      <authenticationrequired/>
      <eventloglevel>55</eventloglevel>
      <auditsuccess>2</auditsuccess>
      <urls>
        <returnurl>https://host/AppCaseSensitveName/</returnurl>
      </urls>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [String Processing Attribute Store Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh599320.aspx) which shows:

```
ToUpper();
```

and

```
ToLower();
```